# How can i give my UIViewController a static background image?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to insert the following code into my `viewDidLoad` and the app shows me the image in a pattern type view. I'm trying to find a way to make the image fit onto the entire screen.

I haven't tried much because I'm fairly new to Swift.

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "GasBackground.png")!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding a `UIImageView` as a subview of your root view:

```
// Creating UIImageView, which holds an image
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "GasBackground.png")
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

// Adding the image view to the view hierarchy
view.addSubview(imageView)

// Make image view to fit entire screen
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
  imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
  imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
  imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
])
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the detailed response man, that worked flawlessly. My only problem is that all my objects that were placed are now hidden behind the background.

Comment: You should then add this before adding other views. Thus, the background UIImageView will stay behind any other view you later add.

Comment: NP. You can also use `view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)`. It should work as well.

Comment: The extra subview and constraints are unnecessary since your ViewController already has a view -- just go into interface builder and change the class of your root view to UIImageView then in `viewDidLoad`    `(view as? UIImageView)?.image = UIImage(named: "GasBackground.png")`

Comment: The way you're suggesting is only possible if using interface builder, though. Wanted to provide a more general answer.